# How to create a dialog built in Qt Designer from a QGIS dockwidget

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqt5

I am building my first python QGIS plugin, which all I want to do is to have a dockwidget that can instantiate a dialog box which I built using qt designer.   I built a simple dialog box inside qt designer with a label, textbox, and ok button.  I created a dockwidget using the QGIS Plugin Builder.

In the main python file, emds.py, the code is below, with the button and click event at the bottom of this code:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSettings, QTranslator, qVersion, QCoreApplication, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAction
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QInputDialog
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog
# Initialize Qt resources from file resources.py
from .resources import *

# Import the code for the DockWidget
from .emds_dockwidget import EMDSDockWidget
from .createproject import Ui_createProject
from .tstDate import DateDialog
import os.path


class EMDS():
    """QGIS Plugin Implementation."""

    def __init__(self, iface):
        """Constructor.

        :param iface: An interface instance that will be passed to this class
            which provides the hook by which you can manipulate the QGIS
            application at run time.
        :type iface: QgsInterface
        """
        # Save reference to the QGIS interface
        self.iface = iface

        # initialize plugin directory
        self.plugin_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)

        # initialize locale
        locale = QSettings().value('locale/userLocale')[0:2]
        locale_path = os.path.join(
            self.plugin_dir,
            'i18n',
            'EMDS_{}.qm'.format(locale))

        if os.path.exists(locale_path):
            self.translator = QTranslator()
            self.translator.load(locale_path)

            if qVersion() > '4.3.3':
                QCoreApplication.installTranslator(self.translator)

        # Declare instance attributes
        self.actions = []
        self.menu = self.tr(u'&EMDS for QGIS 3')
        # TODO: We are going to let the user set this up in a future iteration
        self.toolbar = self.iface.addToolBar(u'EMDS')
        self.toolbar.setObjectName(u'EMDS')

        #print "** INITIALIZING EMDS"

        self.pluginIsActive = False
        self.dockwidget = None


    # noinspection PyMethodMayBeStatic
    def tr(self, message):
        """Get the translation for a string using Qt translation API.

        We implement this ourselves since we do not inherit QObject.

        :param message: String for translation.
        :type message: str, QString

        :returns: Translated version of message.
        :rtype: QString
        """
        # noinspection PyTypeChecker,PyArgumentList,PyCallByClass
        return QCoreApplication.translate('EMDS', message)


    def add_action(
        self,
        icon_path,
        text,
        callback,
        enabled_flag=True,
        add_to_menu=True,
        add_to_toolbar=True,
        status_tip=None,
        whats_this=None,
        parent=None):
        """Add a toolbar icon to the toolbar.

        :param icon_path: Path to the icon for this action. Can be a resource
            path (e.g. ':/plugins/foo/bar.png') or a normal file system path.
        :type icon_path: str

        :param text: Text that should be shown in menu items for this action.
        :type text: str

        :param callback: Function to be called when the action is triggered.
        :type callback: function

        :param enabled_flag: A flag indicating if the action should be enabled
            by default. Defaults to True.
        :type enabled_flag: bool

        :param add_to_menu: Flag indicating whether the action should also
            be added to the menu. Defaults to True.
        :type add_to_menu: bool

        :param add_to_toolbar: Flag indicating whether the action should also
            be added to the toolbar. Defaults to True.
        :type add_to_toolbar: bool

        :param status_tip: Optional text to show in a popup when mouse pointer
            hovers over the action.
        :type status_tip: str

        :param parent: Parent widget for the new action. Defaults None.
        :type parent: QWidget

        :param whats_this: Optional text to show in the status bar when the
            mouse pointer hovers over the action.

        :returns: The action that was created. Note that the action is also
            added to self.actions list.
        :rtype: QAction
        """

        icon = QIcon(icon_path)
        action = QAction(icon, text, parent)
        action.triggered.connect(callback)
        action.setEnabled(enabled_flag)

        if status_tip is not None:
            action.setStatusTip(status_tip)

        if whats_this is not None:
            action.setWhatsThis(whats_this)

        if add_to_toolbar:
            self.toolbar.addAction(action)

        if add_to_menu:
            self.iface.addPluginToMenu(
                self.menu,
                action)

        self.actions.append(action)

        return action


    def initGui(self):
        """Create the menu entries and toolbar icons inside the QGIS GUI."""

        icon_path = ':/plugins/EMDS/icon.png'
        self.add_action(
            icon_path,
            text=self.tr(u'EMDS'),
            callback=self.run,
            parent=self.iface.mainWindow())

    #--------------------------------------------------------------------------

    def onClosePlugin(self):
        """Cleanup necessary items here when plugin dockwidget is closed"""

        #print "** CLOSING EMDS"

        # disconnects
        self.dockwidget.closingPlugin.disconnect(self.onClosePlugin)

        # remove this statement if dockwidget is to remain
        # for reuse if plugin is reopened
        # Commented next statement since it causes QGIS crashe
        # when closing the docked window:
        # self.dockwidget = None

        self.pluginIsActive = False


    def unload(self):
        """Removes the plugin menu item and icon from QGIS GUI."""

        #print "** UNLOAD EMDS"

        for action in self.actions:
            self.iface.removePluginMenu(
                self.tr(u'&EMDS for QGIS 3'),
                action)
            self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(action)
        # remove the toolbar
        del self.toolbar

    #--------------------------------------------------------------------------

    def run(self):
        """Run method that loads and starts the plugin"""

        if not self.pluginIsActive:
            self.pluginIsActive = True
            _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
            #print "** STARTING EMDS"

            # dockwidget may not exist if:
            #    first run of plugin
            #    removed on close (see self.onClosePlugin method)
            if self.dockwidget == None:
                # Create the dockwidget (after translation) and keep reference
                self.dockwidget = EMDSDockWidget()

            # connect to provide cleanup on closing of dockwidget
            self.dockwidget.closingPlugin.connect(self.onClosePlugin)

            # show the dockwidget
            # TODO: fix to allow choice of dock location
            self.iface.addDockWidget(Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea, self.dockwidget)
            self.dockwidget.show()            
            self.dockwidget.btnTestDialog.clicked.connect(self.onTestClick)            

    def onTestClick(self):        
       dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
       dialogui = Ui_createProject()
       dialogui = setupUi(dialog)
       dialogui.show()
```

From qt designer, I created a dialog box called createProject.ui.  The python file generated by pyuic5 looks like:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_createProject(object):
    def setupUi(self, createProject):
        createProject.setObjectName("createProject")
        createProject.resize(702, 329)        
        self.lblStep1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(createProject)
        self.lblStep1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 261, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Verdana")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.lblStep1.setFont(font)
        self.lblStep1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.lblStep1.setWordWrap(True)
        self.lblStep1.setObjectName("lblStep1")
        self.txtProjectName = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(createProject)
        self.txtProjectName.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 20, 391, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Verdana")
        self.txtProjectName.setFont(font)
        self.txtProjectName.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhNone)
        self.txtProjectName.setObjectName("txtProjectName")        
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Verdana")
        font.setPointSize(11)     
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Verdana")        
        self.btnOK = QtWidgets.QPushButton(createProject)
        self.btnOK.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(224, 380, 121, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Verdana")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.btnOK.setFont(font)
        self.btnOK.setObjectName("btnOK")

        self.retranslateUi(createProject)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(createProject)

    def retranslateUi(self, createProject):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        createProject.setWindowTitle(_translate("createProject", "Create New EMDS Project"))        
        self.lblStep1.setText(_translate("createProject", "1) Specify the project name: "))        
        self.btnOK.setText(_translate("createProject", "O&K"))
```

When I load the plugin and press the test button, I get an error saying that on line 3 of my dialog that the object 'EMDS' object has no a attribute  'setObjectName'.

I have also tried adding a static method at the bottom of the python code for custom dialog box:

```
 @staticmethod
  def getCreateProject(parent=None):
      dialog = Ui_createProject()
      result = dialog.setupUi(dialog)
      pjName = dialog.ProjectName()
      return (pjName, result == QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted)
```

and then changing onTestClick event to this:

```
projectName, ok = Ui_createProject.getCreateProject()
print("{} {}".format(projectName, ok))
```

But I get the same error as before: AttributeError: 'Ui_createProject' object has no attribute 'setObjectName'

If I can get a custom dialog box to be displayed from the dockwidget and return the information back, then I can create a plugin that will return multiple pieces of information from the dialog as I need it to do.  I have looked at several examples, but haven't been able to figure how to get this to work within qgis.